# Azure devops authenticate github personal acces token

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

For my current project i want to create an azure devops pipeline for a project which uses a library as a submodule. This library however is in a different organizational unit in github, thus azure devops can't acces it freely.

In order to provide correct authentication i've created a personal acces token for github.

Official microsoft documentation page says i have to excute a specific command in which i have to fill 2 variables. (link to page, subheader **Alternative to using the Checkout submodules option**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts

Either i must be reading it wrong or the workings of this command has changed without updating the documentation.

The following stackoverflow question & answer a user suggested something was changed earlier this year. I've tried this suggestion but it's not working for me.

[How to authenticate to a private Github submodule in a VSTS automated build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052720/how-to-authenticate-to-a-private-github-submodule-in-a-vsts-automated-build)

Could somebody provide me a more detailed version of steps i should take or tell me what i'm doing wrong?

My tries below assuming the following
repo: github.com/libraryorganization
personalaccestoken: 1234ABCD!@#$
base64 encoded personal acces token: MTIzNEFCQ0QhQCMk
base64 encoded personal acces token (**pat:** added in front of accestoken : cGF0OjEyMzRBQkNEIUAjJA==

- git -c http.https://github.com/libraryorganization.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic MTIzNEFCQ0QhQCMk"
  submodule update --init --recursive
- git -c http.https://github.com/libraryorganization.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic cGF0OjEyMzRBQkNEIUAjJA" submodule update --init --recursive
- git -c http.https://github.com/libraryorganization.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic 1234ABCD!@#$"
  submodule update --init --recursive
- git -c http.https://github.com/libraryorganization.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic pat:1234ABCD!@#$"
  submodule update --init --recursive
- git -c http.https://github.com/libraryorganization.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic myusername:mypassword" submodule update --init --recursive
- git -c http.https://github.com/libraryorganization.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic Base64Encode("1234ABCD!@#$:")"
- git -c http.https://github.com/libraryorganization.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic Base64Encode("myusername:mypassword")"
  submodule update --init --recursive

Comment: Are you using YAML pipeline or Classic UI pipeline?

Comment: I'm using a YAML pipeline

Answer (score 0):

It maybe an authentication issue. You need to get the OAuth token into each of the submodule repos.

Make sure you have the build pipeline setting enabled to **Allow scripts access to the OAuth token**. As documented, this stuffs the token into a variable called *`System.AccessToken`*.

It also stuffs the token into a git config setting that you'll see at the end of your get sources step when you run it after enabling the setting. This is how git authenticates to Azure DevOps.

Since you are using script, make sure you have check the allow scripts access to the OAuth token option.

Comment: Do you mean i have to do this in order to acces the variable?
I've tested my script with echo's and i'm able to read the set variable.

Furthermore during testing at one point i decided to ignore the security risks (since i can always retract the acces token) and put my acces token directly inside the script as plain text to rule out if accesing my variable was the problem.

Comment: Hi @AC Select this check box if you want to enable your script to use the build pipeline OAuth token. We often use a secret variable in pipeline to store the basic auth token that you generated. Use that variable to populate the secret in the above Git command. As you have pointed out, the variable just use to shadow your PAT token. If you directly use PAT and still get same error. To further narrow down the issue, you could also directly run that git command in your local environment instead through Azure DevOps. The script is also just calling git command. Check the result.

Comment: Hi @AC Any update on this issue? Have you figured out it?

Comment: I have enabled the OAuth token, but this hasn't changed much.

Locally i have absolutely no problem when using the same commands azure devops uses. Being unable to replicate the problem locally makes it harder to narrow down the issue.
Next week i'll create a testuser on my computer to prevent my locally stored git files from interfering in testing.

For now i have a work-around where i made a copy inside our own organisation and periodically sync them by swapping the origin and pulling all changes.

This feels clunky though so i'd prefer to still get this working.